# MsAccess get Forms Objects in Office 2016

Tags: c#, office-2016, ms-access-2016

In my MsAccess project I want to access the Forms,Reports and Tables objects. 
I need to check the forms fields their height and weight, Tables definition, Reports Queries and so on.
Also I need to do this for MsAccess 2016/365 in C#.

I tried searching on google and this forum but didn't found anything for MsAccess 2016.
Most of the places it says to use Office Interop. But Office 2016/365 doesn't have Office Interop.

My Question how do I get Forms,Table definition, Reports object from Office 2016/365 in C# (with examples if possible)

Thanks,
Nitin Jain

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate download:

[Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)

to be selected to be installed with Visual Studio:

[Configuring a Computer to Develop Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/bb398242.aspx)

Comment: Where is the download for PIA for Office 2016?

Comment: Is it possible to get Forms,Table definition, Reports object from Office 2016/365 in C# without using Interop?

Comment: Not easily. With Access itself, you can call the method SaveAsText for an object and then parse the file. Great fun.